# Get response from server every ten seconds in Android

Tags: java, android, string, android-service, android-volley

I am creating a `Service` that gets response from a server every 10 seconds. In the code below, I make a request every 10 seconds. But even thought the `Service` runs every 10 seconds, the `Toast` shows "fail". What is my code's problem?

```
package gift.charge.free.mci.ir.freecharge;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.*;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Network;

public class GooglePlayService extends Service {
    public GooglePlayService() {
}
private Handler cHandler=new Handler();
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    LetsUpdate();
    return START_STICKY;
}
private void LetsUpdate(){
    cHandler.postDelayed(UpdateMe,10000);
}
private Runnable UpdateMe=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String url ="http://google.com";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
        LetsUpdate();
    }
};
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the proper [permission](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) declared in your manifest?

android.permission.INTERNET